# IrfanView: Can I Batch Convert Images and Set File Size with Command Line?

Tags: command, irfanview

I find using the InfanView 64.exe program/interface to batch convert multiple files tedious because it never remembers the last folder I opened/converted from.

**Is there a way to batch convert a whole folder of .png files to .jpg with the file size 740.00kb with command prompt?**

This is my setup in the program:

- Batch Conversion window (add .png files)
- File Output: JPG
- Options: Set file size to 740.00 KB